# Is there a way for the TcpListener to establish a connection between two TcpClients?

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Let's say S is the server (`TcpListener`) and it is connected to two clients (`TcpClient`) A and B.

Is there a way for S to establish a connection between A and B (so `A <-> B`) and then disconnect from them both?

Basically, I'm looking for a way for two clients to connect to each other (for private messaging, for example) without having either of them needing to port forward or know the other's IP address, since this is inconvenient for the clients.

As shown above, I don't mind the initial involvement of a server (which of course, has to port forward and distribute its IP address).

However, I would like the server to be then able to disconnect from the two clients afterwards (to reduce traffic).

Comment: Your best option is (as I previously mentioned) to have the server forward the packets to the other endpoint. If the server could establish an actual connection between the two that would be a _major_ security risk and flaw. -- Have both of them connect to the server, indicating which endpoint they want the server to forward packets to, then keep forwarding packets that come from A to B, and vice versa.

Comment: @VisualVincent I'm mainly aiming to reduce traffic here, really. Let's say A is the customer and B is the attacker. Then as long as the server is trusted and A's client isn't forged, then I don't see how it is any riskier than communicating through the server since A could be simply made to disconnect if anything fishy is detected from B.

Comment: If you communicate _through the server_ (aka forwarding packets) that's fine. But if you were able to establish a peer-to-peer connection between A and B by using the server, that would be a flaw.

Comment: @VisualVincent A flaw?

Comment: Would it work if the server relayed the endpoints of the clients so that the clients can then connect by themselves?

Comment: A flaw is an exploit, a bug of a sort that can be exploited.

Comment: @usr : How does that work? Isn't it pretty much the same as forwarding the packets?

Comment: @usr Yes - I was hoping for something like that..... would that overcome the port forwarding issue? I'd appreciate a link or an example code demonstrating this if possible.

Comment: @VisualVincent From what usr said, it sounds like the server can back off after the endpoints are relayed. I still don't see how it is a bug, since it isn't any different from two clients (one with tcplistener) connecting to each other with their IP.

Comment: Send them the IP and port. Then make the clients connect to each other.

Comment: @usr But when I first used tcp, I had to set up portforwarding on my router for the server side, and in addition, a firewall message pops up asking if it should allow incoming connections. If the clients just connect to each other, then one of them has to do that?

Comment: If the connection is relayed via the server then it's not the same as connecting directly via their IPs (aka peer-to-peer or P2P). What I meant would be a flaw is if connecting to the server could automatically link the endpoints together via peer-to-peer. And yes, what usr said requires at least one of the endpoints to port forward.

Comment: @usr : What you said is P2P, which will still most likely require at least one endpoint to port forward. The OP wants to avoid this, and the only way I know how to do so is to let the server forward the packets from one endpoint to the other.

Comment: I did not notice that you don't want port forwarding. Maybe TCP hole punching an help? Not sure if that works in practice. I have never seen a software do it and I failed to make it work.

Comment: @usr I've just read up on it, and I'd be interested to try. Do you have a link where I can read about it in relation to VB?

Comment: @VisualVincent I see what you mean by flaw. But surely it'd be fine if the clients would have to do some work too — I didn't necessarily mean it was only the server involved in joining them together. A/B would still have to actively make the connection

Comment: ...which brings us back to square one: port forwarding. -- `But surely it'd be fine if the clients would have to do some work too` - Yes, but if what I said was possible then a non-honest server could connect you to anyone without asking you for permission. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent Yeah, I guess. Although connecting to a non-honest server in the first place is probably bad enough.

Comment: What if you don't know that it's not honest? Anyhow, this would pose a serious security risk.

Comment: @VisualVincent Assuming you trust the developer you downloaded the client from, and the developer implements all of the appropriate security precautions, then the server should authenticate itself when a client connects. This could be done by the server decrypting a message sent using the distributed public key — this will confirm its identity.

Comment: What you were asking for was to connect two `TcpClients` via a `TcpListener`. They don't implement any encrypted messaging, and no authentication whatsoever other than calling `AcceptTcpClient()`. We were speaking general TCP, you cannot compare that with custom protocols.